# is the product of invertible matrices A and B also invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

It's the written question , is the product of the invertible matrices A and B, also an invertible matrix

Comment: It's the answer in the second-to-last question in the "Related" thingy on the left of this page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the product of two invertible matrices also invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762278/prove-that-the-product-of-two-invertible-matrices-also-invertible)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\det(AB)= \det(A)\det(B)$$

What can we say about determinant of a matrix when it is invertible?